# "APN settings are not available for this user"

Tags: settings, nexus-4, 5.0-lollipop, mms, apn

My phone is a stock Nexus 4 from Google with the 5.0.1 Lollipop image from Google.

I've mistakenly hit "reset APN settings". Instead of resetting them to defaults, it wiped them off and grayed out the "add access point" button. I don't know what to do to gain access to this back.

I've tried launching the "Settings" activity from the terminal with root access (using the "su" command), see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21844594/1190096) answer, but the "Settings" activity crashes right after its launch.

What can I do? There seems to be a user permission problem. I'm using the only user account configured on this phone, besides the "guest" user.

Comment: Would factory resetting the phone be a viable option for you (losing all data in the process)?

Comment: Rather not. And it wouldn't guarantee this not happening again anyway, because the phone was freshly reinstalled  when I lost this permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem: I had bad permissions on various MMS-related files that I've copied from a backup, especially inside `data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/`.

Files inside `data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/` have to belong to the **radio** group and be owned by the **radio** user. CHMOD has to be at least **761**.

Comment: So how did you fix the permissions problem ?

Comment: IIRC files inside `data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/` have to belong to the **radio** group.

Comment: This didn't work for me. When I changed permissions in the telephony directory to *660* from *751* and rebooted I got non-stop `com.android. phone` error messages

Comment: Try 761, don't downgrade any permission

Comment: I encountered a different solution, as this didn't work for me. I wrote it up on this [related post](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/113027/access-point-name-settings-not-available-for-this-user?lq=1)