# "Access Point Name settings not available for this user"

Tags: cyanogenmod, nexus-5, 5.1-lollipop, apn

This was probably an issue before but only became an issue when I changed providers in a foreign country. Running CM12.1 nightlies.

I can't connect to data and get the above message when I try to manually enter the APN settings.

I have tried:

1. The [other fix on this site](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/93397/apn-settings-are-not-available-for-this-user) to change permission in `com.android.providers.telephony` to **660** from **751** but that resulted in non-stop error messages from the phone app.
2. Upgrade to the latest nightly with the new SIM inside. No change in service or in ability to change APN
3. Delete the data and cache for the settings app
4. Wipe cache and Dalvik cache.
5. Downgrading to CM 11 milestone

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve the "APN settings are not available for this user" issue?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120707/how-to-solve-the-apn-settings-are-not-available-for-this-user-issue)

Comment: More like that other question is a duplicate of mine, since mine came first, but both ours are about carriers in Brazil. I *highly* doubt that the solution for that question would've worked on mine, since I doubt I didn't at some point reboot and try to edit the APN settings while connected to WiFi. There are enough of these similar APN questions that there should be a wiki post with a list of solutions to try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**sigh** factory reset did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

**edit:** I should mention this fixed issues with *Sprint* for me, but perhaps googling in this vein could lead to finding a similar fix for other carriers.

---

**tl;dr**: I booted to recovery (TWRP), wiped, flashed CM12.1, 5.1 GApps, and the `sprint.zip` file from [this XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/general/fix-sprint-data-to-custom-roms-t2541924) and got LTE back.

---

I'm not positive my issue was the same, but the symptoms are very similar so I'm adding the solution I found. My LTE was working fine on CM12 and CM12.1 for perhaps 3+ months. My phone battery died overnight a couple days ago, and when I powered it on the next morning it didn't have LTE anymore.

Not only that, but I was getting the "APN settings not available for this user" under Settings -> Mobile Networks -> APN settings. After googling, and googling, and googling, I think I tried about every solution suggested for this issue:

- setting /data/data/com.android.providers/telephony/database/telephony.db to higher permissions (e.g. 761)
- deleting telephony.db and telephony.db-journal and letting the system re-create it (theoretically in the "proper" manner)
- using `*#*#4636#*#*` and playing with the preferred network (LTE/GSM/CDMA, LTE only, etc.)
- Turning on wifi, rebooting, waiting a while, and then turning it off and trying to connect to data
- Adding a custom APN, which often wouldn't even save if I had the "APN settings not available for this user", and didn't seem to do anything otherwise.
- I even went back to stock (upgrading radios and firmware in the process) by applying the latest RUU [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2729173). This updated my radios (I was on 3.31.651.2), and allowed me to update PRL/profile while I was at it. I didn't even have LTE from the stock ROM.

I ran into post where someone mentioned "the Sprint APN fix" so I googled for that and ran into [this post](http://androidforums.com/threads/cm12-1-unofficial-beta.905257/), which points to [this XDA post with the fix](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/general/fix-sprint-data-to-custom-roms-t2541924).

Downloading that file (`sprint.zip`) worked great for me, despite that post being ~2 years old. I just did the following:

- boot into TWRP, wipe as usual as if installing a new ROM
- flash CM12.1 (I used the most recent M8 snapshot from 09-01-2015)
- flash 5.1 GApps
- flash the `sprint.zip` file
- wipe cache/dalvik

Rebooted and had LTE right away during setup. Soooo relieved, as this was killing me. I'm still puzzled as to how it could have gotten goofed from a previously working setup, but at least it's behaving now. Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

adapted from: [http://xiaomi.eu/](http://xiaomi.eu/community/threads/cant-set-apn-access-point-name-settings-are-not-available-for-this-user.27446/#post-244517)

my setup: SGS2 aka GT-I9100, CyanogenMod 12.1 Nightly, Android 5.1.1,

**NO GUARANTIES**, following worked for me

for rooted device with file manager

- cd /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony
- rm shared_prefs/preferred-apn*.x­ml
- rm databases/telephony.db*
- reboot

Comment: This worked for me, although I had to boot into TWRP and run these equivalent commands from its File Manager. This was on an HTC One running 12.1 20151007 Snapshot.

Comment: I don't even have the databases folder... All I see is cache and code_cache...

Answer (score 1):

On a brand new Lenovo Yoga Tablet 2, I spent 6 hours trying to get mobile internet to work. New users, reseting to factory defaults, etc. did not work. Did not want to hack/root the device just to try some of the suggestions.

What solved my issue was accidentally tapping VPN in Wireless -> More. Where I have been asked to set PIN in order to get VPN to work. After setting the Swipe PIN, I tried going to cellular data settings again as I had a bright thought that maybe it had somehow set the right permission on the `telephony.db` file. The message was still there, but the plus sign was active for the first time! I got my APN set up and cellular data works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be some misunderstanding between Android of some version and the SIM card. My daughter has a brand new CAT S 42 phone and after updating it to stock Android 11 OTA the mobile data stopped working. The APN list was unavailable and entering it manually froze the settings app. I've tried the sim in my Asus with Android 12 and it didn't work either. However, it worked on a Huawei P20 Pro with Android 10.

The solution was stupidly simple – I called the helpdesk of my provider and they sent me a configuration SMS. Now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem. I found that the message "Access Point Name settings not available for this user" is misleading. It actually means "you haven't added any APNs yet", not "this user does not have the credentials to use this feature."

The solution (if you can call it that) was, at the APNs screen when the message appears, I found the button that allowed me to add a new APN.

Comment: +1 This helped me today.

Answer (score 0):

For nexus 5: settings - more - mobile network - Access Point Names - + (edit access Point) - update name and APN - save.